# Save and retrieve v4 Fragment state

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've read countless topics regarding saving and retrieving the state of Fragments by now. Unfortunately nothing has worked for me and `Bundle savedInstanceState` is always returning null. What i wanna do is implement a "shopping cart" which remembers the items the user selected. To make that possible I just want to save one variable of the Fragment and retrieve it once the Fragment is called again.

Not only do I want to make the fragment retain it's state when called from the backstack, but also when opening it from the `BottomNavigationView`. Or does it even make any difference?

Here is the **parent Activity class** of all the Fragments:

```js
public class ShopMainViewScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements ShopFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, SearchFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ... {

 Fragment mContent;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

  loadFragment(new ShopFragment());
  mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentplace);
 }

 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
   Fragment fragment;

   switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.navigation_home:
     fragment = new ShopFragment();
     loadFragment(fragment);
     return true;
    case R.id.navigation_search:
     fragment = new SearchFragment();
     loadFragment(fragment);
     return true;
    case R.id.navigation_shoppingCart:
     fragment = new CartFragment();
     loadFragment(fragment);
     return true;
    case R.id.navigation_settings:
     fragment = new SettingsFragment();
     loadFragment(fragment);
     return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
 };

 private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
  if (fragment != null) {
   getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentplace, fragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
  }
  return false;
 }
```

This is the **Fragment containing the variable** (`mShoppingCart` which ought to be stored and retrieved).

```js
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {

 private String mTitle;
 private int mQuantity;
 ArrayList < String > mShoppingCart;
 private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

 @Override
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Log.i("onSaveInstanceState", "entered");
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("CART", mShoppingCart);
 }

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Log.i("onActivityCreated", "entered");
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   Log.i("SavedInstanceState", " not null");
   mShoppingCart = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("CART");
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  Log.i("onCreate", "entered");
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if (getArguments() != null) {
   mTitle = getArguments().getString("PRODUCTTITLE");
   mQuantity = getArguments().getInt("QUANTITY");
  }
  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   Log.i("InstanceState", "is null");
   mShoppingCart = new ArrayList < > ();
  }
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  validateCart(mTitle, mQuantity);
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.shoppingcart_fragment_layout, container, false);
 }

 @Override
 public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
  if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
   mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
  } else {
   throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() +
    " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onDetach() {
  super.onDetach();
  mListener = null;
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`savedInstanceState` is only hydrated during configuration changes or when the app is backgrounded & brought back to the foreground. To save the state of a shopping cart throughout a user's session consider using a [view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) attached to the parent activity. You could also try persisting the cart in SQLite if you'd like that data to be retained across multiple sessions.

Comment: resolved the problem by implementing a viewmodel for each screen.